# Unable to submit form values in Angular

Tags: angular

Hi I have a login form

```
    <html>

<head>
  <title>{{pageTitle}}</title>
</head>
<body>
<form [formGroup]="credentials" (ngSubmit)="login()">
  <div class="logindiv container">
        <h2>Login to IDOL</h2>
        <hr />
          <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group col-sm">
                  <label [uxFloatLabel]="regular">Username</label>
                  <input type="text" #mandatory id="usernamd-id" class="form-control" formControlName="username">
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group col-sm">
                  <label [uxFloatLabel]="regular">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" #mandatory id="password-id" class="form-control" formControlName="password">
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                  <button type="button" class="m-b btn button-primary">Login</button>
                  <button type="button" class="m-b btn button-secondary">Cancel</button>
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Its going to submit and I am trying to print values in TS.

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AccessibilityModule, ColorServiceModule, colorSets, IconModule } from '@ux-aspects/ux-aspects';
import { FloatLabelModule } from '@ux-aspects/ux-aspects';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        AccessibilityModule,
        ColorServiceModule.forRoot(colorSets.microFocus),
        IconModule,
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FloatLabelModule
    ],
    declarations: [

    ],
    bootstrap: []
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  public pageTitle = "Login";
  public LoginHeading = "Login to IDOL";
  constructor() { }
  credentials = new FormGroup({
    username: new FormControl(''),
    password: new FormControl('')
  });
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  login(){
      console.log("Button clicked");
  }
}
```

However when I click nothing happens. When the page loads I see the following in the browser console.

```
core.js:16829 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
LoginComponent.html:7 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at FloatLabelDirective.push../node_modules/@ux-aspects/ux-aspects/fesm5/ux-aspects-ux-aspects.js.FloatLabelDirective.hasText (ux-aspects-ux-aspects.js:44667)
    at FloatLabelDirective.push../node_modules/@ux-aspects/ux-aspects/fesm5/ux-aspects-ux-aspects.js.FloatLabelDirective.ngOnChanges (ux-aspects-ux-aspects.js:44644)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:22095)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:23363)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:23325)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:23959)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:23919)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (LoginComponent.html:13)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23911)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23307)
View_LoginComponent_0 @ LoginComponent.html:7
proxyClass @ compiler.js:18239
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugContext_.logError @ core.js:24139
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:15772
(anonymous) @ core.js:18126
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:391
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:150
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:17258
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick @ core.js:18126
(anonymous) @ core.js:18010
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:391
onInvoke @ core.js:17299
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:390
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:150
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.run @ core.js:17213
next @ core.js:18010
schedulerFn @ core.js:13515
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:196
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:134
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:77
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:54
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:47
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:13499
checkStable @ core.js:17268
onHasTask @ core.js:17312
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.hasTask @ zone.js:443
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:463
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:291
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:212
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:601
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:584
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:413
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:238
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:258
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:879
ZoneAwarePromise.then @ zone.js:1012
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:17803
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:78
0 @ main.ts:13
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:78
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
LoginComponent.html:7 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 7, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
View_LoginComponent_0 @ LoginComponent.html:7
proxyClass @ compiler.js:18239
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugContext_.logError @ core.js:24139
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:15777
(anonymous) @ core.js:18126
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:391
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:150
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:17258
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick @ core.js:18126
(anonymous) @ core.js:18010
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:391
onInvoke @ core.js:17299
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:390
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:150
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.run @ core.js:17213
next @ core.js:18010
schedulerFn @ core.js:13515
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:196
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:134
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:77
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:54
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:47
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:13499
checkStable @ core.js:17268
onHasTask @ core.js:17312
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.hasTask @ zone.js:443
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:463
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:291
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:212
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:601
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:584
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:413
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:238
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:258
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:879
ZoneAwarePromise.then @ zone.js:1012
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:17803
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:78
0 @ main.ts:13
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:78
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
```

Comment: I don't see a submit button

Comment: What will happen if you gave yout input fields the name attribut?

Comment: Why use `@NgModule` to decorate the component?

Comment: I have created the submit button. I can't get the values now for username and password.

Comment: Did you try to generate your FormGroup in the ngOnInit method?

Comment: @VinayJoseph `[uxFloatLabel]="regular"` this value is wrong, It should be an input element. https://github.com/UXAspects/UXAspects/blob/develop-1.8.7/src/directives/float-label/float-label.directive.ts#L14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `uxFloatLabel` input should be an `HTMLInputElement`.

https://github.com/UXAspects/UXAspects/blob/develop-1.8.7/src/directives/float-label/float-label.directive.ts#L14

```html
<div class="logindiv container">
        <h2>Login to IDOL</h2>
        <hr />
          <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group col-sm">
                  <label [uxFloatLabel]="usernameInput">Username</label>
                  <input type="text" #usernameInput id="usernamd-id" class="form-control" formControlName="username">
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group col-sm">
                  <label [uxFloatLabel]="passwordInput">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" #passwordInput id="password-id" class="form-control" formControlName="password">
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                  <button type="button" class="m-b btn button-primary">Login</button>
                  <button type="button" class="m-b btn button-secondary">Cancel</button>
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```